# How to make make subfolder invisible in link?

Tags: web-config

What rule can I make in web.config to make this link:

```
https://www.example.com/en/product.asp?vare=38948
```

redirect to:

```
https://www.example.com/product.asp?vare=38948
```

The page works so I guess rewrite would work too.

Comment: Please provide more details, specifically what you have tried code-wise.

Comment: I'm on asp classic. Trying to add rule to web.config to achieve the above.

Trying some thing like:


<rule name="Redirect to Root" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url=".*" />
       <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com/en/$" />
       </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:0}"
        redirectType="Permanent" />
   </rule>

Comment: think I found it with this:

   <rule name="Redirect to Root" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="^en/(.*)" />
       <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?example.com$" />
       </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:0}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
   </rule>


thanks. closing this.